# Simulate Heat Propagation in Vertical Water Column

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I have a vertical cylinder with water, along the height of that cylinder I have `n` temperature sensors. I would like to simulate the change in temperature measured by those sensors. Heat is going to be propagated by conduction and also convection (since cold water is heavier it will end up in the bottom of the cylinder).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Which equations should I take into account?

P.S. I am assuming the cylinder is completely isolated from the outside world and the walls of the cylinder don't transfer heat.

Comment: The cylinder is then closed? Do you have an initial gradient in temperature? Are you heating up the water somehow?

Comment: You'll likely start off with the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) (which I discuss a few times: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A25301+heat+equation). If you're looking for the actual modeling of the fluid flow, rather than the heat transfer, you'll have to add a term to the energy conservation equation (namely $\nabla\cdot\left(k\nabla T\right)$, as mentioned in the Wikipedia entry I link).

Comment: Where is the heat source? if there is no heat source, then temperature is same everywhere and all sensor read the same value.

Comment: @user115350 there's no heat source only different temperatures in the beginning. The temperature the sensor reads is the average temperature of the water around it. In the end it will all have the same temperature but how will it evolve until then?

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't care about the fluid flow just heat transfer. But if hot fluid moves up so does the heat within it.

Comment: Most important would be to mention any kind of symmetries on the initial conditions. Or at the very least some information about the initial conditions. Open-ended like that, your question can only be answered by: numerically integrate the full transport equation.

Comment: @G.Bergeron that's exactly what I want. A numerical solution. What's the full transport equation?

Comment: How about the Navier-Stokes equations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations coupled to the heat equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation ? My comment was meant to be tongue in cheek. Integrating directly those equations without any approximations will be really inefficient computationally and I doubt a naive implementation will be numerically stable... How about stating the expected temperature/pressure range, approximate  dimensions (height,diameter), time frame and some general initial conditions? In any case you need initial conditions to integrate!

Comment: @João Abrantes: Have you seen my answer? A complete description is in the Wikipedia link I had given there. The full set of equations you need to solve consists of equations (1), (2), and (3) given there. As I said in my answer below, feel free to ask if anything is unclear. Note, however, that numerically solving the equations in question is not an easy task.

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes: It seems like you are in good hands with the answers and comments posted. It would be very useful if you could post a diagram of the setup you are interested in with the dimensions of the cylinder clearly labelled. Even if the problem is very clear in your head, it can be difficult for others to visualize the setup just from your description. Most importantly, *please show what is happening to the fluid, and the temperature at the top, bottom, and cylinder walls*.

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes: So, I take it you were not satisfied with the answers you were given? Would you like to tell us what it is you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Since you anticipate having both convective heat transfer generated by fluid motion due to differential buoyancy as well as diffusive heat transfer (aka conduction), you are going to have to solve both a momentum and an energy equation. Assuming the kind of parameter range typical for water as the fluid under reasonable pressures and temperatures, it's likely that the [Boussinesq aproximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boussinesq_approximation_(buoyancy)) will be sufficient for your purposes. Let us know if you need information beyond what's in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough information to tell, but the situation you're describing is called free convection, when the only force acting on the water is the buoyancy created by a temperature difference. For a non-trivial solution, I need to assume that there is some initial unstable temperature imbalance. Namely, that the hot starts at the bottom. Similar situations can be created by heat transfer from the cylinder, but you stated explicitly that this is not the case.

A analytical solution would involve calculating a bunch of non-dimensional constants, with the end goal of characterizing the heat transfer of the system with the Nusselt number. This number is key to understanding how your system is going to behave. The other constants are Reynold's Number, $$Re = \frac{density \cdot characteristic \space velocity \cdot characteristic \space speed }{dynamic \space viscosity},$$ Prandtl number, $$ Pr = \frac{specific \space heat \cdot viscosity}{thermal \space conductivity}, $$ for free convection, there an extra one called the Grashof number $$Gr = \frac{g \cdot \beta (T_s - T_{\inf}) \cdot L^3}{\nu^2}, $$ $\beta$ tells you how much a given fluid expands when it's heated, $\nu$ is dynamic visocity, L is charactaristic lenth. The last two can be combined to for the Rayleigh number $$ Ra = Gr \cdot Pr$$ If you match all these numbers with the right equation (the closest one I can find is free convection between two symmetrically heated, isothermal, vertical plates), you will get an equation for the Nusselt number. $$ Nu = \frac {1}{24} Ra \frac {S}{L} (1 - exp(\frac {-35}{Ra \frac {S}{L}}))^{3/4}.$$ This empirical relationship should be reasonably close to your situation.

That's the analytical solution, but that all seems a litle bit off topic considering your question. If you were looking for someone to steer you in the right direction, I think a study of what all these numbers mean would be appropriate.

If all of that seems a little overwhelming and you have a big processor on your computer, you could always just simulate the system numerically. This would probably be the closest to answering your question, because you have already discretized the system with your n measurement devices.

Comment: No water is being forced through the tube. There are no pumps or heat sources. Given the dimensions of everything how would I solve it?

Comment: Sorry, but that's way too open-ended. The dimensions matter a lot, for example, the diameter could tell you if the flow will be laminar or turbulent. The length/diameter ratio could tell you if you need to consider the entrance region ... and on and on. I've edited the question to show you how to calculate the two dimensionless numbers. With this much information that is the best that I can do

Comment: @João Abrantes: The way you have stated your problem, there is no way around numerically solving the system of partial differential equations I have mentioned. The answer provided above is not related to the problem you have described. The Nusselt number given there is nothing but a non-dimensional version of an *average* heat transfer coefficient of the fluid, which is of no help for solving the problem you have stated (" *simulate the change in temperature measured by those sensors*").

Comment: What system of partial differential equations did you mention. I gave you the analytical solution as per your request "Can anyone point me in the right direction." You are right that it's not quite related, but I contend that this is the 'right direction'. Numerical solutions are a different beast. Perhaps another answer is in order ...